# Fulfilled promise stored rather than the request body

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

The following code sends a post request to an API and then stores the API's response. The object stored is a fulfilled promise, rather than the body. I though I was using the .then properly, as something similar works for a get request.

The following saga is called every time a post request is made. It contains everything from the post to the call to the call to the reducer.

```
function* setData(action) {
        const url = action.payload.url;
        const data_obj = action.payload.data;
        console.log(action);
        try {
        const json = fetch(url, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(data_obj)
        })
        .then(statusHelper)
        .then(response => response.json());
        yield put({ type: "DATA_SENT", payload: json });
        }
        catch (e)
        {
                yield put({ type: ERROR_OCCURED, payload: { error : {message: "An Error occured sending HIT data. Please try again later"}}});

        }

}
```

Below is the statusHelper function. It came from another SO answer (I'll edit in the link).

```
function statusHelper (response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a yield after the fetch. This wound up being the solution for me

```
function* setData(action) {
        const url = action.payload.url;
        const data_obj = action.payload.data;
        let json;
        try {
        const response = yield fetch(url, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify(data_obj)
        });
        //const resp = statusHelper(response);
        console.log('Response: ', response, response.status)
        if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)
        {
                json = yield response.json();
        }
        console.log("JSON: ", json);
        }
        catch (e)
        {
                yield put({ type: ERROR_OCCURED, payload: { error : {message: "An Error occured sending HIT data. Please try again later"}}});
        return;
        }

        yield put({ type: "DATA_SENT", payload: json });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is here

`.then(response => response.json());`

`response.json()` also returns a promise.

You need to `.then` off the `json()` call and return the data.

Comment: Do you mean something like `.then(response => response.json()).then(json => json);`? It still has the same behavior.

Comment: right which actually makes sense now that I think about it. Each `.then` returns a promise

Comment: Aha, do I need to call a resolve somewhere in that case?